# What is the probability of someone else in a room having the same birthday as me and no other people sharing a birthday?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> What is the probability that at least one person in a room of $n$ people (excluding me) has the same birthday as I and that nobody else in the room shares a birthday on a different date? For practical purposes, pretend that leap years don't exist.

---

As a follow-up, what is the expected number of people that have the same birthday as I in a room of $n$ people (excluding me) if nobody else in the room shares a birthday on a different day?

Answer (score -1):

The probability is:

[Explanantion:Spoiler]

> Choose n birthdays from 364 days(except the one which you have), all different dates then select one person whose birthday you want to change to yours and arrange the rest.Total ways of selecting birthdays will be $365^n$.  In case of 366 persons select one person to have same birthday as you and arrange the rest 364 persons with the remaining 364 dates.

$$\frac{\binom{364}{n}\binom{n}{1}(n-1)!}{365^n}:\quad n\le 364\\\frac{\binom{365}1364!}{365^n}:n=365\\0:n\ge366$$
Sorry I know combinatorics and haven't yet covered probability or expected value.

Comment: What about "and that nobody else in the room shares a birthday on a different date"?

Comment: @DigitalBrain that should be easy provided the solution to first part

Comment: I guess you've only calculated probability of "at least two people sharing birthdates" and not "exactly two"

Comment: @DigitalBrain don't guess, revisit it

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong, You're making sure that there's only one person sharing birthday with you, but what about birthdays shared by people except you two?

Comment: @DigitalBrain yes will edit that

Comment: Well, if you're thinking that "and that nobody else in the room shares a birthday on a different date" is another question, I'll suggest to wait for clarification.

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote cause I'm not sur whether you're correct or not?

Comment: @DigitalBrain see edit

Comment: @DigitalBrain "and that nobody else in the room shares a birthday on a different date" is another condition, not another question

Comment: @okarin I knew that!

Comment: I am fairly certain that this solution only meets one of the conditions and not both @DigitalBrain

Comment: @okarin I haven't seen it thoroughly , So, I'm not gonna take any action but Yes, previous version had that problem, I guess you can see revisions.

Comment: @DigitalBrain The statement "select one person to have same birthday as you and arrange the rest 364 persons" implies that this solution doesn't account for the possibility of more people having the same birthday as you.

Comment: @okarin you are misunderstood